# Is Kryptonite some kind of energy source? If not, why?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

...spoilers ahead.

Then why would Zod and his crew carry it on a ship of their own?

[image]

In this scene, divers find a rock on the shallow parts of the Southern Indian Ocean. This rock contained Kryptonite and at this point I'm assuming it came from the wreckage of the World Engine, which was part of Zod's ship.

Why would they carry a substance, which is clearly harmful for them, on their ship? Was it the energy source of the World Engine? What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The World Engine was turning Earth into Krypton

In Man of Steel the World Engine was turning Earth into Krypton, or a planet that would be suitable for Kryptonian life.

The World Engine had already started this process before Superman destroyed it.

This rock would have been part of the terraformed Earth that the World Engine was starting to turn into Krypton.

It was not an energy source for the World Engine.